# How to change the behavior of register on FOS Userbundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

The question is simple. I'm using FOS UserBundle to handle my application users.

I have three roles (superadmin, cm, user) and I want the superadmin can create users through the registration form and add roles (cm or user) to those users.

When the register is ok, the application redirects to register/confirmed url and is logged with the new user created. The idea is to keep the superadmin login and redirect to another page
How I can change this behavior?

With events maybe? REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to just create your own controller that is secured so only superadmin can access it. In the controller, create a form to create new users and do something like:

```
$user = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->createUser();
$form = ;// create a form or look at the FOSUserBundle:Register controller to see how they use the form factory
$form->handleRequest($request)
if ($form->isValid) {
    $user->setEnabled(true); // allows user to login without needing to confirm
    $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->updateUser($user);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will investigate in that way.